# What is the difference between render() and render_template() in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm exploring Flask and have a question about rendering templates. Will the following two statements have any essential difference?

`return self.render('type_edit.html')`

`return render_template('type_edit.html')`

Comment: Where does `self.render` come from? What class is `self` an instance of?

Comment: @dirn `render` comes from `flask-admin`, see: https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.7/_modules/flask/ext/admin/base/#BaseView.render

Comment: Flask-Admin's `render` method sets some admin-related context variables and then calls `render_template`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render_template` is one of the template rendering functions within flask itself. `self.render` is not part of flask by itself, but it's found in some flask packages like [Flask-Admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.7/quickstart/). In those packages, it's used within View classes.

Here's an example of `render_template` being used:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

And here's an example of Flask-Admin's `self.render`:

```
 class IndexView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('admin/index.html')
```